# Textposition not displaying on plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to plot the accuracy of the training and test set of my neural network using plotly.
I want also to add a marker with a text that says when was the maximum value of each but also displays a text that says what that value was. I tried doing something like in [this example](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/).

Here my mcve:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {
    'test acc':  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10],
    'train acc': [3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 8]
}

fig = go.Figure()
color_train = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'
color_test = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
assert len(data["train acc"]) == len(data["test acc"])
x = list(range(len(data["train acc"])))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,
                         y=data["train acc"],
                         mode='lines',
                         name='train acc',
                         line_color=color_train))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,
                         y=data["test acc"],
                         mode='lines',
                         name='test acc',
                         line_color=color_test))
# Max points
train_max = max(data["train acc"])
test_max = max(data["test acc"])
# ATTENTION! this will only give you first occurrence
train_max_index = data["train acc"].index(train_max)
test_max_index = data["test acc"].index(test_max)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[train_max_index],
                         y=[train_max],
                         mode='markers',
                         name='max value train',
                         text=['{}%'.format(int(train_max * 100))],
                         textposition="top center",
                         marker_color=color_train))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[test_max_index],
                         y=[test_max],
                         mode='markers',
                         name='max value test',
                         text=['{}%'.format(int(test_max*100))],
                         textposition="top center",
                         marker_color=color_test))

fig.update_layout(title='Train vs Test accuracy',
                  xaxis_title='epochs',
                  yaxis_title='accuracy (%)'
                  )
fig.show()
```

However, my output fire is the following:
[image]

As you can see, the value is not being displayed as in the example I found.
How can I make it appear?

Comment: Hi Agustin, do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular we need the `data` dataframe or a way to reproduce it.

Comment: Updated question with mcve. Data was indeed a dataframe but in the new example I changed it to a simple dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd only like to highlight a few certain values, use `add_annotation()`. In your case just find the max and min Y for the X that you'd like to put into focus. Lacking a data sample from your side, here's how I'd do it with a generic data sample:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default='browser'

fig = go.Figure()

xVars1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
yVars1=[0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5]


xVars2=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
yVars2=[0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=xVars1,
    y=yVars1
))


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=xVars2,
    y=yVars2
))

fig.add_annotation(
            x=yVars1.index(max(yVars1)),
            y=max(yVars1),
            text="yVars1 max")
fig.add_annotation(
            x=yVars2.index(max(yVars2)),
            y=max(yVars2),
            text="yVars2 max")
fig.update_annotations(dict(
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=7,
            ax=0,
            ay=-40
))

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

Comment: This seems to work. Give me a sec to finish putting it into my code and I will mark it as the solution. However, what is `xref` and `yref` suppose to be for?